# Query Solr: I want to query fields with values example collection_id:408 and collection_name:Birth Records

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I want to query Solr for a search that has a name of "Manter".

My query:

```
Manter AND doc_type:newspaper
```

That works fine

But when I want to query:

`Manter AND collection_name:Birth Records` I get no results

or even just `collection_name:Birth Records` This does exist

How can I correct my query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
collection_name:"Birth Records"
```

and if you just filtering the records -

```
q=manter&fq=collection_name:"Birth Records"
```

Comment: to explain that a bit because the OP may not know: inserting collection_name:"Birth Records" as a fq (filterquery) filters by that value but doesn't interfere with scoring (in constrast to putting it in the query (q) ) Moreover, filterqueries have good performance characteristics becacuse they can be cached seperately